# Preventing low-priority tasks from dominating Postgresql server

Tags: postgresql, performance

I have a side project which involves scraping several websites and aggregating their content, which can be queried via an API. As such, I have a few background tasks which update/insert millions of rows per day. When these tasks are running, the API is noticeably slower - 5-10 seconds of delay instead of <1 second. It's not practical to provide a hard rate limit on the background task. The background worker would be leaving performance on the table 99% of the time, and there still wouldn't be enough performance left over for larger surges to the API.

I'm looking for a practical way to prevent the background worker from hogging the Postgresql server. I was thinking I could have 2 servers in a cluster - one would be read/write, which the background worker would connect to, and the other one would be read only. Since writes would be propagated to both servers anyway, I'm not sure if that would actually help performance.

Comment: Would it be plausible that the background tasks push the high-priority data out of the cache?

Comment: Is the bottleneck CPU or I/O?

Comment: @CL. Yes, that's definitely plausible. The bottleneck is I/O.

Comment: Regularly running dummy API queries might help.

Comment: @CL. I'm not sure how effective that would be. There are a lot of search parameters that can be varied, and the cache isn't big enough to hold the entire database in RAM. (16GB of RAM for a 30GB database that grows by roughly 7GB per month)

Comment: @SitephenD77 If the cache wasn't big enough, you would have the performance problem all of the time not just when the tasks are running.  You should try the idea before dismissing it.

Comment: Turn on track_io_timing and use auto_explain to do the equivalent of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`.  Maybe your queries are just generally inefficient in a way which is still good enough when there is no other load, but not when there is other load.

Comment: @jjanes The queries are fairly intensive - I'm grabbing anywhere from 1K to 10K records from the database for processing in the backend. It's difficult to figure out what dummy API requests I should be making because there are so many parameters to vary, with each one touching different parts of the database.